# Nextflow: Missing output file(s) expected by process

Tags: bioinformatics, nextflow

I'm currently making a start on using Nextflow to develop a bioinformatics pipeline. Below, I've created a `params.files` variable which contains my FASTQ files, and then input this into `fasta_files` channel.
The process `trimming` and its scripts takes this channel as the input, and then ideally, I would output all the `$sample".trimmed.fq.gz` into the output channel, `trimmed_channel`. However, when I run this script, I get the following error:

**`` Missing output file(s) `trimmed_files` expected by process `trimming` (1) ``**

The nextflow script I'm trying to run is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env nextflow

params.files = files("$baseDir/FASTQ/*.fastq.gz")
println "fastq files for trimming:$params.files"
 
fasta_files = Channel.fromPath(params.files)
println "files in the fasta channel: $fasta_files"

process trimming {

input: 
file fasta_file from fasta_files

output: 
path trimmed_files into trimmed_channel

// the shell script to be run: 
"""
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkdir trimming_report
cd /home/usr/Nextflow

#Finding and renaming my FASTQ files
for file in FASTQ/*.fastq.gz; do
    [ -f "\$file" ] || continue 
    name=\$(echo "\$file" | awk -F'[/]' '{ print \$2 }') #renaming fastq files. 
    sample=\$(echo "\$name" | awk -F'[.]' '{ print \$1 }') #renaming fastq files.
    echo "Found" "\$name" "from:" "\$sample"
    if [ ! -e FASTQ/"\$sample"_trimmed.fq.gz ]; then
        trim_galore -j 8 "\$file" -o FASTQ #trim the files
        mv "\$file"_trimming_report.txt trimming_report #moves to the directory trimming report 
    else
      echo ""\$sample".trimmed.fq.gz exists skipping trim galore"
    fi
done

trimmed_files="FASTQ/*_trimmed.fq.gz"
echo \$trimmed_files
"""
}
```

The `script` in the process works fine. However, I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding or missing something obvious. If I've forgot to include something, please let me know and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nextflow does not export the variable `trimmed_files` to its own scope unless you tell it to do so using the [`env` output qualifier](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#output-env), however doing it that way would not be very idiomatic.

Since you know the pattern of your output files (`"FASTQ/*_trimmed.fq.gz"`), simply pass that pattern as output:

`path "FASTQ/*_trimmed.fq.gz" into trimmed_channel`

Some things you do, but probably want to avoid:

- Changing directory inside your NF process, don't do this, it entirely breaks the whole concept of nextflow's `/work` folder setup.
- Write a bash loop inside a NF process, if you set up your channels correctly there should only be 1 task per spawned process.

Answer (score 4):

[Pallie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10524064/pallie) has already provided some sound advice and, of course, the right answer, which is: environment variables must be declared using the [`env` qualifier](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#output-env).

However, given your script definition, I think there might be some misunderstanding about how best to skip the execution of previously generated results. The [cache](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#cache) directive is enabled by default and when the pipeline is launched with the `-resume` option, additional attempts to execute a process using the same set of inputs, will cause the process execution to be skipped and will produce the stored data as the actual results.

This example uses the Nextflow [DSL 2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html) for my convenience, but is not strictly required:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.fastq_files = "${baseDir}/FASTQ/*.fastq.gz"
params.publish_dir = "./results"


process trim_galore {

    tag { "${sample}:${fastq_file}" }

    publishDir "${params.publish_dir}/TrimGalore", saveAs: { fn ->
        fn.endsWith('.txt') ? "trimming_reports/${fn}" : fn
    }

    cpus 8

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(fastq_file)

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path('*_trimmed.fq.gz'), emit: trimmed_fastq_files
    path "${fastq_file}_trimming_report.txt", emit: trimming_report

    """
    trim_galore \\
        -j ${task.cpus} \\
        "${fastq_file}"
    """
}

workflow {

    Channel.fromPath( params.fastq_files )
        | map { tuple( it.getSimpleName(), it ) }
        | set { sample_fastq_files }

    results = trim_galore( sample_fastq_files )

    results.trimmed_fastq_files.view()
}
```

Run using:

```
nextflow run script.nf \
    -ansi-log false \
    --fastq_files '/home/usr/Nextflow/FASTQ/*.fastq.gz'
```